# Is 'about' the correct preposition here?

Tags: prepositions

A: Why did she pass out?

B: I think she's just a little nervous **about** flying.

She doesn't like flying. Is 'about' the correct preposition?

Comment: Yes, 'about' is the correct word here. And "She doesn't like flying" does not mean exactly the same thing, though it's close. Someone could dislike something but not be so nervous about it that they pass out; they could be extremely nervous about something but still not dislike it.

Comment: @rcook - That  would make a good answer.